# Excel: Returning values from a range that haven't already been specified

Tags: excel

I have a dataset in long format with a unique ID representing people at different points in time. I already have a list of ID's with the first code, but would like to add a column for the second and third code, if available.

An example of the data, with what the output should look like at the bottom
[image: example]

I already have the first two columns in this example. I was thinking I would specify that I want to look at the values that are *not* the first code, and output a different code in the range if available, otherwise it returns blank. I also want to be able to use the command with few modifications in a third cell for a third code, again as long as it exists.

Ideally this can all be done without the use of vba, however if that would be easier, then by all means go ahead. Any solution not necessarily following my logic map are appreciated as well. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It can be done with array formulas.  A quick google search on "Distinct list based on two criteria" turned up the following which you could modify to meet your need: https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/27/how-to-create-a-unique-distinct-list-where-other-columns-meet-two-criteria/

Comment: Whoops! I'm sorry, I guess I didn't know what to search for. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: It is doable with formulas, but it is a hassle, it is easier with VBA, use dictionaries

Comment: @Hector  Happens to me a lot.  becomes so much easier when I have the right search terms.  It comes with time and practice getting the right terminology...I still do not have it.